# Auto scroll accordion to the top of the clicked section

Tags: jquery, scroll, accordion

I have the following code for an accordion content holder that works fine. I cant seem to workout how to auto-scroll the page to the top of the clicked section. Right now the container opens but the page doesnt scroll at all.

Please help !
G

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name = "viewport" content = "user-scalable = no">

<title>TEST</title>
<link href="style/english.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="style/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="style/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico">
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"></script>


<!--Accordian menu JQuery-->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
        $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
            active: 'none',
            heightStyle: "content",
            collapsible: true,
            /*heightStyle: "fill"*/
        });
    });


</script>


<script>
 function Clicked1(){  
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({ active: 0 });
 } 

 function Clicked2(){  
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({ active: 1 });
 } 

 function Clicked3(){  
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({ active: 2 });
 }

 function Clicked4(){  
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({ active: 3 });
 }

 function Clicked5(){  
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({ active: 4 });
 }

 function Clicked6(){  
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({ active: 5 });
 }

</script>
<!--Accordian menu JQuery-->

</head>
<body>

<div id="mainContainer"  style="background-color:#009edb;">

    <!--Header-->
    <div id="headerContainer">

        <a href="index.html"><img src="images/header.jpg" width="1000" height="110" border="0" /></a>

    <!--Menu-->
    NAVIGATION CODE
    <!--Menu-->
    </div>
        <!--Header-->

        <!--Body-->
    <div id="mainBodyContainerWhite">
    <div id="topExtra"></div>

        <!--Spotlight-->
    <div id="spotlightBoxContainer">
    <div id="spotlightBoxFull" style="height:440px;"><img src="images/case_spotlight.jpg" width="986" height="508" usemap="#Map2" border="0" />
          <map name="Map2" id="Map2">
            <area shape="rect" coords="1,1,247,169" href="#section1" onclick="Clicked1()" id="scroll" />
            <area shape="rect" coords="494,2,740,169" href="#section1" onclick="Clicked2()" id="scroll" />
            <area shape="rect" coords="248,170,492,338" href="#section1" onclick="Clicked3()" id="scroll" />
            <area shape="rect" coords="741,171,983,335" href="#section1" onclick="Clicked4()" id="scroll" />
            <area shape="rect" coords="3,338,247,506" href="#section1" onclick="Clicked5()" id="scroll" />
            <area shape="rect" coords="491,338,739,507" href="#section1" onclick="Clicked6()" id="scroll" />
          </map>
    </div>  
    </div>
    <!--Spotlight-->


    <div id="accordion">
    <!--Split--> 
    <h3 style="border-top:solid 1px #009edb; border-bottom:solid 1px #009edb;">ACCORDIAN 1</span></h3>
        <div class="accordion-content">
            <div id="ContainerLeftInner">
            <div class="textInner">
            TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST.
            </div>
                </div>
            </div>

    <!--Split--> 
    <h3 style="border-top:solid 1px #009edb; border-bottom:solid 1px #009edb;">ACCORDIAN 2</span></h3>
        <div class="accordion-content">
            <div id="ContainerLeftInner">
            <div class="textInner">
            TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST.
            </div>
                </div>
            </div>

    <!--Split--> 
    <h3 style="border-top:solid 1px #009edb; border-bottom:solid 1px #009edb;">ACCORDIAN 3</span></h3>
        <div class="accordion-content">
            <div id="ContainerLeftInner">
            <div class="textInner">
            TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST.
            </div>
                </div>
            </div>

    <!--Split--> 
    <h3 style="border-top:solid 1px #009edb; border-bottom:solid 1px #009edb;">ACCORDIAN 4</span></h3>
        <div class="accordion-content">
            <div id="ContainerLeftInner">
            <div class="textInner">
            TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST.
            </div>
                </div>
            </div>

    <!--Split--> 
    <h3 style="border-top:solid 1px #009edb; border-bottom:solid 1px #009edb;">ACCORDIAN 5</span></h3>
        <div class="accordion-content">
            <div id="ContainerLeftInner">
            <div class="textInner">
            TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST.
            </div>
                </div>
            </div>

    <!--Split--> 
    <h3 style="border-top:solid 1px #009edb; border-bottom:solid 1px #009edb;">ACCORDIAN 6</span></h3>
        <div class="accordion-content">
            <div id="ContainerLeftInner">
            <div class="textInner">
            TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST.
            </div>
                </div>
            </div>

    <!--Split--> 
    </div>    
    <!--Spotlight-->    
    </div>
</div>

    <!--Body-->

<div id="footerContainer"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to your question but just an helpful suggestion to minimize a bit of your js code.

- First remove the `onclick` attributes from the areas
- Add the below jQuery code.
- Next remove the 14+ lines of code with function names like `Clicked1()`, `Clicked2()`, etc.

**JS**

```
$('#Map2 > area').click(function () {
    $("#accordion").accordion({ active: $(this).index() });
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks alot palash - appreciate it (helps me learn more), but then how does the JS know which accordion section to open up when clicked on a specific area ? each 'clicked()' area opens up a separate accordion section.

Comment: Thanks for the appreciation @GeekyGaj. We are using the `$(this).index()` for that. If the first area is clicked then the `$(this).index()` value is `0` and hence the active accordion will be the first one. Next if the 2nd area is clicked then the `$(this).index()` value is `1` and hence the active accordion will be the 2nd one and so on..

Comment: @palash, i used your technique but after i've removed all the onclick, the clicks dont work at all.

Comment: @GeekyGaj Try putting alerts inside the `click` method like `alert('Clicked!')` & `alert( $(this).index() )`...

Comment: @palash i've updated the link http://www.grouporigin.com/clients/zadco/23102013/case_studies.html - i added the alerts inside the click function - but i think it would not be correct. And if you look at the code, it doesnt slide anymore

Answer (score 0):

Geeky Gaj;

Hey buddy.  Palas makes a good point and you can incorporate his suggestion into my solution.  I have a jfiddle with a working example (I did not link the function to a click able link) where it scrolls to the open div when loaded. Here is the [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TGv6E/6/).

The key is placing a span tag around a piece of text at the top and calling scrollTop with the position of the top of the span tag (by id).  I believe this will accomplish what you are looking for.

```
$(function() {
     $( "#Accordion" ).accordion({
         collapsible: true,
         active: false
     });
     Navigate(0);

});

function Navigate(dest) {
    $( "#Accordion" ).accordion({
        active: dest
    });
    $(window).scrollTop(($("#acc" + dest).offset().top - 60));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay Andrew, i tried to follow your jfiddle example and i seems to scroll 20px or so on the first click, but after another second click on another link, it scrolls right to the bottom. What am i doing wrong ? Here is the link if you want to have a look: http://grouporigin.com/clients/zadco/23102013/case_studies.html

Comment: I looked at your code, it appears that you don't have the link (the pictures as far as I could tell) attached to an event.  Your going to want to add onclick="Navigate(x)" to the links in question where x is a number.  That number should correspond to a id of the element you want to scroll to.  I updated the jsfiddle again.

Comment: Sorry, I was half asleep when I wrote that comment.  The jsfiddle works and I put comments in it to explain whats going on.  Take a look and if still seems complicated to implement come on back and we can figure something out.

Comment: thanks a million mate. I checked the jfiddle link, but it doesnt seem updated (cant see any comments) http://jsfiddle.net/TGv6E/4/ - is this the correct link ? Also i just noticed - when i add your code my top dropdown menu stops working, seems like an issue with the 'Navigate(0);' line. If i remove this line the dropdown menu starts to work again.

Comment: I updated my code from your comment (as i could not see an updated jfiddle) - seems like now when i click a link on the image the page moves down but none of the accordions open up. What i did was just added the 'Navigate(0);' line to the JS (which has stopped the menu droping down), and replaced all onclicks in the image map links from onclick="Clicked1()" to what you mentioned onclick="Navigate(1)". I have an updated link for you to compare just in case: http://grouporigin.com/clients/zadco/24102013/

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to change the jfiddle link to the next updated number, the answer has the working link and here is another link just in case. http://jsfiddle.net/TGv6E/6/